# How can i add image in scroll bar with html and css?

Tags: html, css, image, scrollbar

First of all, excuse me for my level of English, I'm French and you know our reputation :)
So here is my problem:
I'm trying to customize my scrollbar but with an image I've tried many things to do it but I don't really know java and the only guide I've seen was only in java...
I don't know how to do it so if you have any advice don't hesitate to send it.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue, you'd want to use the `webkit scrollbar` css api. Please keep note that this api isn't available for both Microsoft Edge and Firefox. For more information, please visit [this url](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp). Below is an example for your case:

```css
.main {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 2px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 2.5px solid black;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.main::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  /* this sets the width of the bar, in the div.main (::-webkit-scrollbar is fro the body/html)*/
  width: 20px; /* change for scrollbar width */
}

.main::-webkit-scrollbar-track { 
  /* scrollbar background */
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.main::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: red; /* will leave after image loads */
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/100/400");
  background-size: cover;
}

.main::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  /* feel free to set this for when the mouse is over the bar */
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non asperiores
    quos, suscipit officiis, impedit sapiente unde modi quia voluptatibus, id
    cupiditate nesciunt. Officia, in animi distinctio commodi perspiciatis ad
    eligendi! Earum ab porro perferendis inventore, asperiores quaerat quis
    voluptate ducimus odio officia numquam nobis ipsum consectetur deleniti
    natus aspernatur, a temporibus illo culpa quia, similique iste quas sunt.
    Architecto, rerum. Qui, nostrum. Molestias, placeat maiores dignissimos id
    laboriosam eos error possimus voluptas ipsum aut rerum culpa nesciunt
    quaerat ipsam sapiente veniam exercitationem dolorum esse illo explicabo
    similique? Labore, ab aperiam. Blanditiis animi qui velit nobis fugit! Eius
    laborum necessitatibus aperiam sequi explicabo! Alias, neque. Ad veniam
    dolor, doloribus assumenda laboriosam vel necessitatibus minima dolorum fuga
    ipsa beatae quos, distinctio debitis? Voluptate, neque. Fugiat accusamus,
    excepturi, quam aliquid beatae consectetur laboriosam commodi nesciunt et
    dolor delectus illo perferendis sapiente ab voluptatem dicta quod! Laborum
    possimus sapiente repellat itaque ex facere recusandae?
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I have another problem : my image was too big so I changed it and now it's 20px wide but now the image doesn't go down completely and I don't know why, I also deleted the background size setting because it was making my image look weird

Comment: @lower The image must fit the size of your scrollbar. Could you please open another problem or just send me your code? Thanks!

Comment: I have already opened another problem and I wonder if you have any idea how to solve it.